# i want to get the values from two tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, inner-join

i got two tables

```
office       accnt        id
------------------------------
HR           poop         1 
HR           fart         2
EXEC         poop         3
```

and

```
id          number
-----------------------
1               2
1               2
1               1
2               5
2               1
3               6
```

and what i wanted to be the output is like this

```
id         office        accnt        number
--------------------------------------------
1            HR          poop            5
2            HR          fart            6
3            EXEC        poop            6
```

and here's what I've tried so far

```
SELECT        AccntTbl.office, AccntTbl.accnt, SUM(NumberTbl.Number)
FROM          AccntTbl INNER JOIN
              NumberTbl ON AccntTbl.Id = NumberTbl.Id
```

and sadly i can't get what i want..glad for any help.. :)

Comment: Suggestion: you better change your profile picture to something less disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.office, a.accnt, SUM(n.Number)
from AccntTbl a INNER JOIN 
NumberTbl n ON a.AccntTbl.Id = NumberTbl.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Accnt.id,Accnt.office, Accnt.accnt, SUM(Num.Number)
FROM   AccntTbl Accnt INNER JOIN
              NumberTbl Num ON Accnt.Id = Num.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a `GROUP BY` with the id, the office and the accnt.

```
SELECT 
  acc.id, acc.office, acc.accnt, 
  SUM(num.Number) AS number
FROM AccntTbl acc
JOIN NumberTbl num
  ON acc.Id = num.Id
GROUP BY 
  acc.id, acc.office, acc.accnt
```